# How can I have a single fixed image fit to screen when the body is always centered

Tags: html, css, background, center

So maybe it is just the way I am centering my body because I am displaying it as a centered table in the html.

```
html {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

body {
    width:100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#background{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:url('image.jpg'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

based on that code I can see that the image would start at the beginning of the body, which starts centered so the image will start there and I have blank space that should not be there; I want the content in the body to be centered, but the background should not be so it will fit to screen in the right way. I tried transferring my center code to the container, but that didn't work. I have looked around for an hour or two and all the answers have not worked for me. Any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking?  Can you make an example on jsFiddle or somewhere else?  Because `position: fixed;` will take an element out of the flow of the page and position it in relationship to the viewport, NOT parent elements.  Is that what you are experiencing?

Comment: I think he's just going for a fullscreen background.  Which there are no actual positions listed for.  `top: 50%; left: 50%; margin: -50% 0 0 -50%;` kind of thing.

Comment: here is the jsfiddle that shows my issue http://jsfiddle.net/xJJ2V/17/. And the reason why the position must be fixed is so that with all the content, when scrolled down the image stays there and does not continue to stretch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about not centering your body, can you wrap that in a container ie. "mainContainer" and center that instead?

*Edited*: Here is a fiddle forked from yours http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/C4Spd/

```
<html>
    <body>
       <div id="background"></div>
       <div id="outerContainer">
           <div id="mainContainer">
               <div id="box">
                   <p>This is some content</p>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>

#outerContainer {
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
#mainContainer{
    width:100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#background {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url('http://mytwopiasters.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/ocean.jpg');
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
#box {
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    position:fixed;
    height:100px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
```

Comment: @RyanSaxe Is the site available to public? if you don't mind me looking at your full html/css so I can tinker in Firebug.

Comment: no, it's not up at the moment, but here is a quick jsfiddle that I put together that has the basics of it...http://jsfiddle.net/xJJ2V/17/

Comment: @RyanSaxe awesome, please vote up and/or mark question as answered :) it'd be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Did you reset the margins for the page?

```
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
```

Also, if your desired result is to have a full screen background, why not this:

```
body {
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Check this link for alternate methods:  http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I am trying to get the body content centered with a background that is fixed and fit to the full screen...That works if body is not centered